# SAP HANA Authorisation Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: search table error: [2950] user is not authorized

Tags: authorization, hana

At the moment I try to understand SAP HANAs authorisation concept.

I assigned the analytic user the following rights:

- select on _SYS_BI, _SYS_BIC
- execute on REPOSITORY_REST
- root package: REPO_READ

If I create an analytic privilege on an information view and assign this privilege to the user then the user is able to query the information view.

On the other hand the modeller does not need this analytic privilege to query the information view. So there must be another way to allow the user to query the data - right? And I try to understand how.

Without the analytic privilege the user gets the following error:

**Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: search table error:  [2950] user is not authorised**

**So which privilege is missing?** What is search table error?

Answer (score 1):

This question really is more about concepts and not so much about how to do something specific. I recommend to use the [SAP Community Network (SCN)](https://scn.sap.com/community/hana-in-memory) community for this kind of question.

Generally speaking, modeller roles tend to have a "see all" privilege, which allows them to see all data.
The "search table error" is a general error message used by SAP HANA and can indicate basically any problem with data access. The specific information are provided in the details part of the error message. In this case that's : **[2950] user is not authorised**